# cannot import name 'AsyncIOSchedular'

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, apscheduler

```
import asyncio
import trollius
import datetime 
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOSchedular
```

This gives

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncIOSchedular'
```

python version: 3.6.5

os is ubuntu

Note: APSchedular is installed version==3.6.3 and its BackgroundSchedular is working just fine.

What can be the reasons behind this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's spelled "Scheduler" not "Schedular".